# .htaccess mod_rewrite rule "works", but server sends 404 code!

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file on my webroot:

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|pdf|mp3|flv|swf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.htm$ /$1.php [nc,L,QSA]
```

The purpose of the Rewrite rule is to change any request for a page with a .htm extension to a request for the same filename with a .php extension (unless the file with .htm extension actually exists). This rule seems to "work" in the sense that if I ask for a page with a .htm extension, I get the PHP content. This is what I want, but at the same time HTTP header inspector tools report that the website is giving a 404 response. What's weird is that my tools report that in the body of THE SAME RESPONSE, the server returns the correct HTML generated by the PHP code. That seems like a contradiction: page not found, but here's the content you wanted anyway??

If I force the server to send a 200 code ([R=200]), I get an "Internal server error" response, and if I force it to send a 301 code ([R=301]), the result is that the browser makes 2 HTTP requests instead of 1, and the second one ends up being a 404 anyway (but I still get the desired HTML in the response body!). I'm confused!!!

Comment: You might get better answers at: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It sounds like your PHP script has a call to `header()` somewhere that sends back a 404 response. What kinds of things are you doing in `mystery_file.php`?

Comment: You might be on to something, Tim. My PHP files are using a CMS to query page content stored in a database. I didn't write the CMS, so it might be sending a 404 header somewhere in the code but not exiting. As a test, I added a PHP page that did no backend querying, just a few lines of simple code. Then I requested that page with a .htm extension, got the correct PHP-generated content back, and no 404 this time.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The CMS software was sending a 404 header due to an error in the page code. Once I fixed that, I stopped getting a 404 code in the response header.

Comment: You may want to mark your answer as correct then.  Adding the CMS name as a tag on the question is also a good idea, as it helps people to find appropriate questions when looking for answers later.